# Android: How and where to use get(position)?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How do we implement get(Position) using arraylist in android? An example will be really helpful. Thanks

```
id | artist | image 
1    bob      image.jpg
2    tom      image2.jpg
```

I am storing this information from sqlite to arraylist. I want to implement something like this in android and fetch the records one by one.

```
 private void Data(int position){
    /*
     * Get the data from the list of the new position
     */
     String text = myThings.get(position).text;    
     String image = myThings.get(position).imageURL;
     myTextView.setText(text);
     myImageView.loadImage(image);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myArrayListOfStrings.get(0);
```

That will get you the value of the object at 0 in the arraylist `myArrayListOfStrings`